# How to disable Click even on sidebar menu in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar in angular. I want to disable click even on sidebar menu items so that people are not able to navigate. I want them to go through a flow.
However disable [routerLink] mess up the css.
Any tips or tricks how to solve the issue.

HTML Code for Sidebar Navigation

```
<ul class="nav">
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{ menuItem.class }}">
  <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
    <i class="nc-icon {{ menuItem.icon }}"></i>
    <p>{{ menuItem.title }}</p>

  </a>

</li>
```

How the sidebar looks now:

[image: Sidebar snapshot]

I want to show the user on which page he is in sidebar but do not allow to navigate through sidebar.I will make them go through a flow using go back and go next button in each component.

I have tried using [disabled] but it doesn't work and few other solutions from SOF.However none of them seems to work. If I remove [menuItem.path] from RouterLink then it mess up my css.

Comment: try - [attr.disabled]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attr.disabled`, instead of disabled

```
 <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{ menuItem.class }}">
  <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" [attr.disabled]="your condition ? '' : null">
    <i class="nc-icon {{ menuItem.icon }}"></i>
    <p>{{ menuItem.title }}</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above issue by adding `class="disabled"` in the anchor tag.
So my code now looks like this:

```
 <ul class="nav">
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{ menuItem.class }}">
  <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]"  class="disabled">
    <i class="nc-icon {{ menuItem.icon }}"></i>
    <p>{{ menuItem.title }}</p>

  </a>

</li>
```

Comment: [attr.disabled] - this didn't work out ? I have checked using - [attr.disabled] and its working..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use steppers rather than an unordered list. here is an example
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/overview#nbsteppercomponent

Answer (score 0):

try adding new css class with help of `[ngClass]`

```
.custom-cursor {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```